# access local jetty webserver from inside LAN

Tags: jetty

I have just installed a jetty 9 webserver on my windows 7 Professional laptop and i am struggling to access it using the external IP. Chrome just says "This webpage is unavailable" when i go the the address `"http://117.***.**.**:8080/"` from the same laptop.( This is the external IP of my router found out from whatismyIP.com. I have used * here to mask the actual IP). I can access it from the same laptop with `"http://192.168.1.3:8080/"` and `"http://localhost:8080/"` without any problems. My laptop internal IP is 192.168.1.3, which connects to the internet through a DLink WiFi router at 192.168.1.1. I have also forwarded the TCP port 8080 on my router to 8080 at 192.168.1.3 using the router's admin page and restarted the router. It just doesn't seem to work. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

*Edited on 26-Aug-2013 :*

ok the problem is my router does not seem to support port forwarding from within the LAN. So when i access `"http://117.***.**.**:8080/"` from outside the LAN, i can see my Jetty webserver homepage without any problems. But if i try accessing the same address from within the LAN, it does not work. It works from within the LAN only if i use the localhost or internal IP adddress. If there is some way to make the port forwarding work within the LAN as well, it would be awesome.